# Mysql select and sort many to many

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

> table car : cid(fk), carname

```
 cid :       1     2    3     4
 carname : car1, car2, car3, car4
```

> table driver :did(fk), drivername

```
 did :          1     2    3     4
 drivername :  Tom   John Joe   Sam
```

> table cardriver : carid(fk), driverid(fk)

```
 carid :          1     2    3     1
 driverid :       1     1    1     3
```

So I want to get all the cars that a particular driver drives like this :

```
Tom : car1, car2, car3
```

I can do it using Group_concat but how can i sort it on site?  The site will display the same as above and I want to get all the drivers who drive it when I click on the car ( Tom can drive car1 and Joe can drive car2)

```
select d.drivername , group_concat(c.carname SEPARATOR ', ') as car from driver d 
inner join cardriver cd on d.did=cd.driverid 
inner join car c on c.cid = cd.cerid group by cd.driver_id
```

Comment: sort it on site? - there is no site in the data..

Comment: sort it in the query... and there is a typo (driverid / driver_id ?)